# ReplaceAll not working on XML input

Tags: java, string, replace, character-encoding

I am working on a java program that reads in XML and generates an output XML. I am having a problem replacing some of the characters in my read in file.

The following is my method:

```
 public void readTemplateXML() {

    BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                    path), "UTF8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    xml = sb.toString();
    xml = xml.replaceAll("&lt;", "\\<"); //This is not working.
}
```

I am just outputting the "xml" string to an xml file and I am still getting "<":

```
&lt;addressLine1&gt;Main Street&lt;/addressLine1&gt;&#13;
```

Is there anyway I can replace these characters with <, > ?
The encoding of the file is UTF-8.

EDIT:
the xml string is correct after the replace alls. I am using it as text content in another methods xml node:

```
        // inner request element
        Element request = doc.createElement("con:request");
        request.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(xml));
        rootElement.appendChild(request);
```

After this the content is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

short answer :

Syntax:
Here is the syntax of this method:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

Parameters:
Here is the detail of parameters:

regex -- the regular expression to which this string is to be matched.

replacement -- the string which would replace found expression.

code  :

```
       String xml="&lt;addressLine1&gt;Main Street&lt;/addressLine1&gt;&#13";    
       xml = xml.replaceAll("&lt;", "\\<"); 
       xml = xml.replaceAll("&gt;", "\\>"); 
       xml = xml.replaceAll("&#13", ""); 
       System.out.println( xml );
```

result :

```
<addressLine1>Main Street</addressLine1>
```

Comment: I have also tried regex. 
Can you explain why `xml = xml.replaceAll("&lt;", "\\<");` is not valid ?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @L337BEAN check my answer again , and let me know what is your problem?

Comment: I inputted your answer but I am getting the same result. I have updated my question with more detail

Comment: @L337BEAN please define new question for your new request , and mark accepted for my answer